# do you have to specify all routes to conform to rest api?

Tags: rest

I am currently working on a project where some collection's items should not be deleted do i have to specify all methods (/GET, /POST, /PATCH, /DELETE) to conform to rest api ? or I can bypass the ones I don't need.

Comment: What do you mean by "specify all routes"? `GET`, `POST`, etc are *methods*. If a route only needs or makes sense for some methods, then only define it for those methods (I think that's what you mean by "bypass").

Comment: sorry my bad, methods yea. That is exactly what I mean.
to be honest I got lost of different people teaching these concepts as they always add all methods to the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, status code **404 Not Found** - means document not found, and api endpoint IS NOT DOCUMENT.

Second, According to https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html, they propose to use status code  **501 Not Implemented.**

> The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the
> request. This is the appropriate response when the server does not
> recognize the request method and is not capable of supporting it for
> any resource. (c) Wikipedia
>
> The server either does not recognise the request method, or it lacks
> the ability to fulfill the request.

So, at least i do this personally, if i don't want user to delete full collection of users (for example) i either give 501 status code, or, 403, if admin user can delete all other users, and ordinary user - cannot.

So, in case of users api, this status code can be used

- GET /api/v1/user -> 200 (list users)
- POST /api/v1/user -> 201(create new user, for example, admin can do it)
- GET /api/v1/user/{{userID}} -> 200/404 (get profile of one of users, or 404 if user not found
- PUT/PATCH/POST /api/v1/user/{{userID}} -> 204 (because returning response with profile updated is not required here - we assume client already knows profile)
- DELETE /api/v1/user/{{userID}} -> 200 if admin deletes one of user, or 404 if user not found, or 403 if ordinary user tries to delete other one.
- DELETE /api/v1/user/ -> 501 (deleting all users is dramatic, and this is exactly the case being discussed. But it can be good idea to explain to api user that this endpoint exists, and is not implemented, that returning confusing 404 meaning document not exists, but endpoint != document)

Comment: so from what i understand it is always okay to implement only the methods needed or at least send status code 501 for unsupported ones, as an extra step right ?

Comment: yes, its ok if method is implemented as nearly empty code that just sends 501, it can be implemented in future, while not breaking compatibility with api clients being developed